# Fetching ExactTarget DB from Google Sheets

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, google-apps

I'm currently building a consolidated report from multiple sources in Google Sheets.

I need to access some data that is located on ExactTarget from Google Sheets. I'm using Google Apps Script to access the other DBs (BigQuery or Analytics), but I can't seem to find the way to do it with ExactTarget.

The main thing is that it should be relatively "live", as we want this report to be updated automatically hourly or so.

Any recommendation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I really want to get eMail send data pulled into Google Sheets as well. I've been using Supermetrics for other data sources, but not sure how to get ExactTarget integrated as its not one of their built in connectors, however it does let you pull in from Databases. http://supermetrics.com/product/supermetrics-for-google-drive/